# How to make a MessageBoxButton move?

Tags: c#

I've made a TextBox that retains what you type, and when you click the button associated it gives you a messagebox. When people want to click no, I want the button to change location so people cannot click it so they are forced to click yes. Can you help me? Here is the code:

{

```
 MsgBox = new CustomMsgBox();
 MsgBox.label1.Text = Text;
 MsgBox.button1.Text = btnOK;
 MsgBox.button2.Text = btnCancel;
 MsgBox.Text = Caption;
 result = DialogResult.No;
 MsgBox.ShowDialog();
 return result;
```

}

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2.Location = new Point(25, 25);
    }
    private void button2_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        button2.Location = new Point(+50, +50);
    }
    private void button2_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        button2.Location = new Point(+100, +100);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create your own form and make it act like a messagebox. Instead of creating a MessageBox, you will instantiate your own form and so that you can handle the buttons on it.

Comment: K i've done that but now i have another problem ,the button is moving just one time not everytime i put my mouse over it.
{

     MsgBox = new CustomMsgBox();
     MsgBox.label1.Text = Text;
     MsgBox.button1.Text = btnOK;
     MsgBox.button2.Text = btnCancel;
     MsgBox.Text = Caption;
     result = DialogResult.No;
     MsgBox.ShowDialog();
     return result;
}

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            result = DialogResult.Yes; MessageBox.Show("Asa credeam si eu");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button2.Location = new Point(25, 25);
        }
        private void button2_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            button2.Location = new Point(+50, +50);
        }

Comment: @camin10 - You should really create another post for your other question.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).